# Should I put the complete Tornado tree under version control or not?

Tags: cvs, vxworks

I finally have a hardware guy that is insterested in controlling the firmware.

This is for vxworks firmware.  The tornado (2.2.1) gui creates a project file that has a list of files that were modified but they seem to be from all over the directory tree.

So I am tempted to just controll those files.

Comment: Tornado is a vxworks specific IDE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking in the Tornado target tree as a whole is a good idea in my opinion. 
The biggest advantage is, that service packs and patches are propagated automatically to other team members and _even_more_important_ to the build machine. An other advantage is, that if you need to debug something in an old version, you have the correct header files and libraries.

See [VxWorks / Tornado II FAQ - 1.12 Version control](http://www.xs4all.nl/~borkhuis/vxworks/vxw_pt1.html#1.12)

Comment: +1: Once again, I type too slowly - found the same reference.

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for someone else with real experience could provide more insight.
I'm also using Stackoverflow to capture google searches.